# Converting comma separated string to integer array in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to convert the Comma separated string into an integer array (integer[]) to use in Where clause.

I have tried cast, `::Int` which didn't work. Appreciate your input

Example

```
Table A   |  Table B
ID        |  Set_id
2         |  14,16,17
1         |  15,19,20
3         |  21
```

My Query:

```
Select * 
from Table a, table b 
where a.id in b.set_id
```

Comment: This is a horrible design. Why do you do that?

Answer (score 52):

You need to convert the string to a proper integer array if you want to use that for a join condition.

```
Select * 
from Table a
  join table b on a.id = any(string_to_array(b.set_id, ',')::int[]);
```

---

But a **much** better solution would be to properly normalize your tables (or *at least* stores those IDs in an integer array, not a varchar column)

Comment: This may happen when some raw data was stored as "1,23,456" in some file.  You have to convert those to array of integers for less storage usage and better performance.

Answer (score 9):

```
Select * from Table_a a, table_b  b
where a.id = any(regexp_split_to_array(b.set_id,',')::int[]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use unnest() function. unnest function is to used expand an array to a set of rows.
`Select * from Table_a a, table_b  b where a.id in (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(b.set_id, ',')::int[]));`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this is nearly 4 years old) with existing answers. How does this improve upon what's already here?