# Postgresql, convert a CSV string into an array

Tags: postgresql, function

Postgresql version 12. In a function, want to delete the users with the specific IDs (column "id" bigint). The IDs are passed in as a CSV string(VARCHAR) like this:

```
'1,2,3'
```

and the function is like this:

```
remove_users(in ids varchar)
```

and in the function want to do:

```
delete from users where users.id in ids
```

or

```
delete from users where users.id = any(array _ids)
```

how the conversion from csv string to int array be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting comma separated string to integer array in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304552/converting-comma-separated-string-to-integer-array-in-postgres)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use built in array functions:

```
delete from user
where id any(string_to_array('1,2,3', ','))
```